# How do you initialise a const array of TGUID from Interface type data, in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, interface, guid, array-initialize

I want to initialise an array like this -

```
Const MyArray : Array[0..0] Of TGUID = (IInterface);
```

But it results in -

```
[DCC Error] Test.pas(10): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TGUID' and 'string'
```

So to see what would happen I tried this -

```
Const MyArray : Array[0..0] Of String = (IInterface);
```

Which results in this!

```
[DCC Error] Test.pas(10): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TGUID'
```

How strange! Surely IInterface is one or the other, but it seems to stubbornly transform into the wrong type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pull the GUIDs from the interface declarations and declare them as (string) constants. You can then use these constants in your interface declarations and your array constant declarations. The compiler accepts valid GUID strings where TGUID is expected. Invalid strings result in E2204 "Improper GUID syntax" compile error.

```
const
  MyGuid1 = '{99BDAB12-B1B6-41B0-9BF1-2C1DB3D8EC70}';
  MyGuid2 = '{8C7CD303-8D81-469B-99ED-E1F163E9036F}';

type
  IMyInterface1 = interface
    [MyGuid1]
  end;

  IMyInterface2 = interface
    [MyGuid2]
  end;

const
  MyArray: array[0..1] of TGUID = (MyGuid1, MyGuid2);
```

Comment: I like this the best, it's a bit more manual work than I'd hoped but it looks like it doesn't leave any traps for any subsequent programmers, which is the most important thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use a const array you have to set it up with const values like this:

```
const GuidArray: array[0..0] of TGuid=
  ('{84DBCC66-72AA-4806-AE28-B55FC5B83FC8}');
```

Comment: Ah, that works. I wanted to pull the GUIDs directly from the interface type though, as keeping them in sync manually is a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to return your array of GUIDs. (I use this technique for constant date values.)

- It's not "truly" a constant, but should be usable wherever you'd ordinarily use the constant.
- But it also cannot be modified using the "assignable typed constants" option. *Cheating not allowed :)*
- So it has a tiny advantage over setting a global in the **initialization** section.
- Also, it's less manual work than moving the GUIDs used by the interfaces into their own constants.

You have the choice of returning a dynamic or fixed size array.

**Option 1**

```
type
  TGUIDArray = array of TGUID;

function GetMyInterfaces: TGUIDArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2);
  Result[0] := IMyInterface1;
  Result[1] := IMyInterface2;
end;
```

**Option 2**

```
type
  TGUIDArray = array[0..1] of TGUID;

function GetMyInterfaces: TGUIDArray;
begin
  Result[0] := IMyInterface1;
  Result[1] := IMyInterface2;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried in C++Builder:

```
const TGUID g = __uuidof(IInterface);
const TGUID MyArray[] = {__uuidof(IInterface)};
```

I suspected that the explicit keyword __uuidof might avoid the problem you have, but it merely replaces it with something very similar.While the first line works fine, the second one yields:

```
[C++ Fehler] Unit1.cpp(9): E2034 Konvertierung von 'const _GUID' nach 'unsigned long' nicht möglich
```

(in English: [C++ error] Unit1.cpp(9): E2034 Conversion from 'const _GUID' to 'unsigned long' not possible)

Comment: That's interesting, is there a __uuidof equivalent in Delphi? Just doing Const MyGUID : TGUID = IInterface; produced an error for me.

Comment: I have no idea. I tried some casts like TGUID(IInterface) but nothing worked. Maybe this is the time where some Delphi compiler engineer should chime in? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: The following compiles:

```
procedure Blah(const MyArray: array of TGUID);
begin
  //...
end;

Blah([IInterface, IDispatch]);
```

Maybe you can use this approach.

Comment: That's quite a nice approach. It happens to not really suit my case, but I can imagine often being able to rework things into this method

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of IInterface.

Comment: I actually need the GUIDs though, not instances of IInterface

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I discovered using the fact that traditionally, consts are not really const in delphi. Requires a compiler switch to return to this behaviour (In D2007)

```
{$J+}
Const MyArray : Array[0..0] Of TGUID = (());
{$J-}
```

In initialization section -

```
MyArray[0] := IInterface;
```

Comment: I guess in that case it would be easier to just use "var MyArray...". :-)